# Appcelerator Studio Crashes on Safari Launch?

Tags: safari, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I'm working on an iMac 27-inch, Late 2012 (macOS High Sierra)

When I open Safari, Appcelerator Studio crashes immediately! I couldn't figure that out why this is happening.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check what is the error reported in the crash log? Just look for main thread crash and search in the google - this might give some clue.

Not sure if it's related to this:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=465693

When crash happens, you'll see a rectangular dialog with a title of JVM Terminate on your screen and Studio will disappear. This indicates Java itself has crashed, but it creates a log file in the process.

By default, the crash file should be in either the Studio installation directory, or in the system temp directory, most likely with a file name of **hs_err_pid*.log**. If you still could not locate it, follow the directions here:

Finding your Error Log

On OS X, the location is ~/Library/Logs/Java/*.crash.log or ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter, and the file will have the word java in its name.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Crashes_and_Freezes

Comment: I couldn't check. Because I think you're right! Java got an update. After that, Studio stays intact :)